# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

I discovered my own error, can't understand why some down voted. See first comment

SOLUTION:

```
if(!empty($_GET['lang']))
{    
$uri = 'http'. ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 's' : null) .'://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$lang_folder = $_GET['lang'];
$ses = $_COOKIE['ccUser'];
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE ".$glob['dbprefix']."CubeCart_sessions SET lang='".$lang_folder."' WHERE sessId='".$ses."'");
header("Location:".substr($uri, 0, -8));
die();
}
```

where a bit of code is creating "too_many_redirects":

```
if(!empty($_GET['lang']))
{    
$uri = 'http'. ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 's' : null) .'://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$lang_folder = $_GET['lang'];
$ses = $_COOKIE['ccUser'];
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE ".$glob['dbprefix']."CubeCart_sessions SET lang='".$lang_folder."' WHERE sessId='".$ses."'");
header("Location: $uri");
}
```

I need to GET the URL the visitor was and reload the page after changing the website language.

Any hints folks?

Comment: Uh probably is because i'm requesting the server the same URL over and over again loool

Comment: Use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the address where the user is coming from.

Comment: Please escape the data you get from the user!! For example with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Comment: also when doing a redirect. add die() afterwards.

Comment: @Souza You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. It will help make it clear that this question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` includes `?lang=...` which results in `if` statement being true everytime you redirect.

Comment: Yup, that's what i said in my comment (First comment)
Thanks anyway